# Drag and drop ffmpeg batch file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have little to nothing experience with ffmpeg and found this nice drag and drop script but it only work for one file at the time. Can it be modified to work for multiple files at the same time?

```
pushd %~dp0
echo Encoding 720p ... 
ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -vf scale=1280x720:flags=spline,format=yuv420p,"subtitles='%~n1'%~x1" -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 -preset veryfast -crf 16 -maxrate 20M -bufsize 25M -x264-params colormatrix=bt709 -c:a copy "%~n1_720p.mp4"
popd
echo Done. 
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a to run a `for` loop on `%*` to perform the action for each item then use the metavaiables in the `ffmpeg` command (which will be each dragged item):

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
echo Encoding 720p ... 
for %%i in (%*) do if not exist "%%~ni_720p.mp4" (
   ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~i" -vf scale=1280x720:flags=spline,format=yuv420p,"subtitles='%%~ni'%%~xi" -map_metadata -1 -movflags faststart -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 -preset veryfast -crf 16 -maxrate 20M -bufsize 25M -x264-params colormatrix=bt709 -c:a copy "%%~ni_720p.mp4"
)
popd
echo Done..
```

*Note!* this code is untested as I am posting from mobile.